# Calling a functor "pointed to" by an iterator inside a template function

Tags: c++, functor

The template function `apply_all` below takes an iterator range (`itBegin -> itEnd`) for a sequence of *binary function objects* stored in a vector. As I iterate, I want each functor to be called with the two given arguments `a` and `b`. The result is to be written to the `Output Iterator` (`outIt`), but I have no idea how to call a functor using the iterator variable:

```
template <typename InIt, typename OutIt, typename A, typename B>
void apply_all(InIt itBegin, InIt itEnd, OutIt outIt, const A& a, const B& b)
{
    for(auto it = itBegin; it != itEnd; it++)
    {
        *outIt = ... // how do I call the functor pointed to by *it?
        outIt++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `(*it)()`?

Comment: `(*it)(a, b)`, but yeah, try that and if it doesn't work, report back with an error message.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JeJo this looks to be the dual of transform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++17, simply using [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)

```
*outIt = std::invoke(*it, a, b);
```

or plain (if not a pointer to member function)

```
*outIt = (*it)( a, b);
```

Comment: "*outIt = (*it)( a, b)" worked for me thanks. But I have to ask: why is the syntax like that?

Comment: @AbdelAleem Glad that helped. The `it` is an iterator, which needs to be dereferenced so that we can get the underline function pointer/ function. Then we call the function with arguments.

Comment: @AbdelAleem `*it` names a function, but the function call operator is higher precedence to the indirection operator, so parentheses are required. If you had a range-for loop like `for (auto f : std::ranges::subrange(itBegin, itEnd))` then `f(a, b)` [would be sufficient](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33f5e020fe80f941)